# iPhone Popup in CSS

Tags: css

I am making a website which is designed to look somewhat like an iPhone UI, and I am using a popup. By popup (I don't know what it's actually called) I mean this sort of thing:

[image]

My question is, how would I make the buttons on it? I tried it, and `-webkit-border-image doesn't work.`

Thanks!

Comment: An example of what you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: @j08691 I did. I said -webkit-border-image didn't work.

Comment: okay @Zungy , i changed my example below, to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. One way is to use some webkit CSS properties, like -webkit-border-radius. Combine this with other [webkit-specific properties](http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/general/webkit_css_styles) and you will (after a long time) get rather good results.

However, there is an easier method. You can also make a button image (by photoshopping your screenshot) and use that as a background for the link. Than you just have to find the right font and probably use some [webkit text shadow](http://www.webkit.org/blog/85/introducing-text-stroke/): an easy method to get great results!

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand your question right.
If you are allowed to use CSS3 have a look for [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

An example: (NEW LINK)  http://jsfiddle.net/MGr3t/2/

CSS:

```
.button{
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-image: url("http://www.krause-sohn.com/images/background.jpg");
    border-color: 1px solid black;
}
```

HTML

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="send"><br/><br/>
<img class="button" src="http://www.domain.com/background.jpg" width="100" height="40">
```

Comment: No.. I meant the button using an image.

Comment: @Zungy the example with background image and with an image as a button [NEW LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/MGr3t/2/)